# Summing information from API/divs

Tags: reactjs, api, sum, calc

I got access to the API and I stored them using useState. I have a question - how can I easily sum values of two divs together in React? I don't want to use jQuery, I want it to be nice and clean. Any ideas? Here you can see a part of the relevant code. Maybe useRef?

```
 const [details, setDetails] = useState({})

  const search = evt => {
    if (evt.key === "Enter") {
      fetch(`${api.base}forecast?q=${query}&units=metric&APPID=${api.key}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(result => {
          setDetails(result);
          setQuery('');
          console.log(result);
          return result;
        })
----

<div className="detail--icon">Morning: {Math.round(details.daily[1].temp.morn)}°c</div>
<div className="detail--icon">Day: {Math.round(details.daily[1].temp.day)}°c</div>
<div className="detail--icon">Night: {Math.round(details.daily[1].temp.night)}°c</div>
<div className="detail--icon">Humidity: {details.daily[1].humidity}%</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what do you mean by sum values of divs, but given that the content you're showing in the repeating divs differs quite a bit (`Math.round` is not used everywhere, suffixes are different, data is not part of a single object, e.g. first three are part of `details.daily[1].temp`, but last one is part of `details.daily[1]`), I'd suggest two options:

**A helper function which accepts the content between the tags (`content` param will be JSX):**

```
const getDetail = (content) => {
   return (
      <div className="detail--icon">{content}</div>
   )
}
```

And use it like:

```
{getDetail(<>Morning: {Math.round(details.daily[1].temp.morn)}°c</>)}
```

Note that you need to put `<>` and `</>` in-between to make it a valid JSX (this is shorthand for `React.Fragment`).

**Or a small component (probably slightly less amount of code):**

```
const Detail = (props) => (
   <div className="detail--icon">{props.children}</div>
)

...

<Detail>Morning: {Math.round(details.daily[1].temp.morn)}°c</Detail>
```

You can go further by storing all of the content of the rows in an array of JSX elements and do a `Array.map` on it, but I'm not sure how readable that would be.

Another thing apart from the markup refactoring I'd suggest is to store `details.daily[1]` or `details.daily[1].temp` in a variable before rendering and just write daily or daily.temp where necessary.